# Qual é a origem do uso da palavra "pai" em português brasileiro aparentemente para acentuar algo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões

Por exemplo, no FIFA 2020, o comentador brasileiro, Tiago Leifert, as vezes diz "Respeito pai. Cristiano Ronaldo está em jogo hoje", ou algo parecido. Não é a primeira vez que vejo a palavra "pai" ser utilizada para enfatizar algo. Tipo "Olha estas jogadas pai".

Qual é o verdadeiro significado da palavra "pai" nestas situações? Em quais outras circunstâncias "pai" pode ser utilizada da mesma maneira? E qual é a origem desta usança? Não é que os brasileiros usam "pai" em vez de "pah"? Não me parece porque os portugueses usam "pah" noutras circunstâncias, tipo "E pah, não sei!".

Já agora, a minha lingua materna é o português de Portugal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"O Pai" é traduzido com "The man" (ou seja "o protagonista") [nesta entrevista com o Neymar](https://www.facebook.com/BleacherReportFootball/videos/296618294739981/), onde o Neymar é "o pai", ou seja, "the man"! Esta tradução é consistente com o uso que vi até agora desta expressão. "O pai" é uma expressão aparentemente popular no Brazil, porque seja o Neymar que o entrevistador (brasileiro) conhecem bem esta expressão.

Já agora esta expressão é também usado pelo novo comentador do FIFA 2021, penso Gustavo Villani, quando fala sobre "O Pai, Cristiano Ronaldo".

Answer (score 2):

Devo dizer que não conheço esse uso, mas, dado o contexto, parece ser uma forma de tratamento - e então as seguintes frases seriam equivalentes:

> Olha estas jogadas, pai.
>   Olha estas jogadas, cara.
>   Olha estas jogadas, mano.
>   Olha estas jogadas, meu.
>   Olha estas jogadas, véio.
>   Olha estas jogadas, bicho.

Outra possibilidade seria uma referência a Deus, como se estivesse a ele se dirigindo:

> Olha estas jogadas, Pai.

Mas esta me parece menos provável.

Comment: Vê a minha resposta.

Comment: Outros geneanônimos (se me permitem o neologismo) também são usados com esse propósito interjeitivo. 'Tio', pela população geral, principalmente no Nordeste brasileiro: "Qual foi, tio, fez isso por quê?". 'Filho', de mais velhos a mais jovens: "«Filho, relaxe e tome uma água.», disse a senhora idosa ao homem que trabalhava na casa". Outros exemplos podem ser encontrados em diversos dialetos.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a palavra não será "pai", mas soa parecido.

O que provavelmente é dito no jogo é:**"pra aí"**, ou **“p’raí”** o que soa a:**"prà-í"**. Numa pronúncia que não acentue o **"r"**, fica finalmente:**"pà-í"**.

Começa com a contração de **"para"** ficando **"pra"** e como a palavra seguinte é **"aí"** juntam-se as duas vogais contíguas com acento grave **"`"**.

Portanto, na verdade a frase provavelmente é: **"Respeito para aí."**

(Os tradutores do jogo devem ter dado umas gargalhadas ao prever a perplexidade que esta opção ia causar aos ouvintes.)